Matching entries and exits in kdb
Given the following table, with closing prices and given entry locations
t: ([] close: 18 2 4 8 5 7 3 10 17; entry: 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0);

I'd like to figure out the correct exit locations. The condition is that the difference between closing prices >= 3, and of course that the trade can only closed once per entry, and after entry.
My incorrect attempt is:
t: update exits: (close - close[first where entry=1])>=3 from t;
show t;

yielding:
close entry exits
-----------------
18    0     1    
2     1     0    
4     0     0    
8     0     1    
5     0     1    
7     1     1    
3     0     0    
10    0     1    
17    0     1 

What's expected is:
close entry exits
-----------------
18    0     0    
2     1     0    
4     0     0    
8     0     1    / exit
5     0     0    
7     1     0    
3     0     0    
10    0     1    / exit
17    0     0 

What's the correct, vectorized approach in idiomatic kdb+/q to obtaining the expected result?

See the follow up at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78656361/intraday-exits-for-gb-scale-ohlcv-data

Updated my answer to handle the assumption that @cillianreilly kindly pointed out.
The updated answer tracks the portfolio of entries and any exits made will update the list of portfolio.
q)t:([] close:18 2 4 8 5 7 3 10 17; entry:0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0);
q)/ x[0]:portfolio remaining
q)/ x[1]:exits
q)f2:{{x[0],:$[y`entry;y`close;()];if[x[1]:any exits:2<y[`close]-x 0;x[0] _:first where exits];x}\[(`long$();0b);x][;1]};
q)update exits:f2 t from t
close entry exits
-----------------
18    0     0
2     1     0
4     0     0
8     0     1
5     0     0
7     1     0
3     0     0
10    0     1
17    0     0
q)t:([]close:2 6 10;entry:1 1 0);
q)update exits:f2 t from t
close entry exits
-----------------
2     1     0
6     1     1
10    0     1

I believe there is no need to iteratively update the original table. For larger tables the computation is much slower.
q)data:([] close:10000?100; entry:10000?01b);
q)t:update exits:0b from data;
q)o:select close,index:i from t where entry;
q)f:{index:?[x;((>;`close;2+y`close);(>;`i;y`index);(not;`exits));();(first;`i)];update exits:1b from x where i=index};
q)\t c:f/[t;o]
1233
q)f2:{{x[0],:$[y`entry;y`close;()];if[x[1]:any exits:2<y[`close]-x 0;x[0] _:first where exits];x}\[(`long$();0b);x][;1]};
q)t:data;
q)\t m:update exits:f2 t from t
61
q)all c=m
close| 1
entry| 1
exits| 1


This solution assumes that each entry will exit before the next entry point e.g. it won't work for: t:([]close:2 6 10;entry:1 1 0)

You’re absolutely right. I wrote the solution with the assumption of the above. I will have to come up with an updated solution to handle that

@cillianreilly I've updated my answer. I believe it should handle the assumption you pointed out now.

Thanks @Maurice Lim ! I've added a follow up to your answer for large, grouped data above. Have a look.

@marital_weeping what is your meta ohlcv? Could you provide a sample as I cannot reproduce the error. I tried with the following and it works: N:1000; ohlcv:([] ticker:N?\NOK`YHOO`CSCO`ORCL`AAPL`DELL`IBM`MSFT`GOOG; date:asc N?.z.d; close:N?100; entry:N?01b);`

Yeah Maurice, my bad, it works just fine. The issue was that the close column was of type long in the original example, but got switched to float later. I just needed to change it to long to float in your code and it works. However, it's very slow given that my dataset is about 2.3GB. I'm asking another question in a few minutes. Please have a look.

Here's the follow up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78656361/intraday-exits-for-gb-scale-ohlcv-data

My solution does not apply to by clause. An updated solution to handle that is required. I have answered your question in the above follow up. Please check if the solution satisfies your conditions.

This should be what you're looking for. For each entry, the functional select finds the first index in the table that:

Is strictly greater than the close price plus 2
Appears after that close price
Is not already an exit

Once we have the index, we update the original table. We then repeat the procedure iteratively across all entry points
t:update 1h$entry,exits:0b from t
o:select close,index:i from t where entry
f:{
        index:?[x;((>;`close;2+y`close);(>;`i;y`index);(not;`exits));();(first;`i)];
        update exits:1b from x where i=index
        }

q)f/[t;o]
close entry exits
-----------------
18    0     0
2     1     0
4     0     0
8     0     1
5     0     0
7     1     0
3     0     0
10    0     1
17    0     0


Thanks for the excellent answer @cillianreilly !

I think there is no need to iteratively update the original table. For larger tables the computation is much slower.
