Intraday Exits for GB scale OHLCV data
I have a large (~2.3GB) ohlcv dataset containing columns for intraday 15m data.
date       ticker   open    close   high    low     volume exchange time                          sma50    sma25    atr14    relVol10 entry exits
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2024.06.20 IBM 2963.25 2964    2965.7  2960.4  400564 NASDAQ      2024.06.20D13:30:00.000000000 2943.033 2940.838 8.835116 2.619959 0     0    
2024.06.20 IBM 2963.95 2948.1  2964.6  2947.3  333112 NASDAQ      2024.06.20D13:45:00.000000000 2943.034 2941.708 9.43975  1.827534 0     0    
2024.06.20 IBM 2948.5  2952.9  2955.35 2946.55 220532 NASDAQ      2024.06.20D14:00:00.000000000 2943.085 2943.05  9.394054 1.090741 0     0    
2024.06.20 IBM 2953.15 2958.5  2960    2952.5  288016 NASDAQ      2024.06.20D14:15:00.000000000 2943.261 2944.386 9.258764 1.352764 1     0    
2024.06.20 IBM 2958.55 2952    2962.9  2950.1  343157 NASDAQ      2024.06.20D14:30:00.000000000 2943.208 2945.4   9.51171  1.49124  0     0    
2024.06.20 IBM 2951.7  2951.35 2952.9  2943.05 429613 NASDAQ      2024.06.20D14:45:00.000000000 2943.145 2946.594 9.535873 1.675764 0     0    
2024.06.20 IBM 2951.15 2946.6  2953    2940.9  937451 NASDAQ      2024.06.20D15:00:00.000000000 2942.802 2947.832 9.719025 3.195037 0     0    
2024.06.20 IBM 2947.7  2949    2950.55 2943    565435 NASDAQ      2024.06.20D15:15:00.000000000 2942.585 2949.112 9.564095 1.546279 0     0    


Given the entry locations entry which are boolean flags, I would like to find out the exits (also boolean flag) given the condition that the exit close >= 1.02 entry close, if the condition is not met I'd like to exit at the end of the day.
I've tried two approaches based on the answers to my previous question Matching Entries and Exits in KDB . I believe they're functionally correct but both are excruciatingly slow -- to the extent that given the size of my dataset they never finish, and keep taking more and more memory till the system becomes unusable.
@cillianmurphy's approach
o:select close, index:i, ticker, date from ohlcv where entry;
f:{[x;y]
    index:?[x; ((>;`close;1.02 * y`close);(>;`i;y`index);(not;`exits)); (); (first;`i)];
    if[null index; index:-1 + count x]; / if index is 0N, then return last index
    update exits:1b from x where i=index
 }
r: f/[ohlcv; o];

@Maurice Lim's approach
/ @MauriceLim
f2:{
    {
        x[0],:$[y`entry; y`close; ()];
        if[x[1]:any exits:1.02*x<y[`close] 0; x[0] _: first where exits]; x
    } \ [(`float$();0b); x][; 1]};
r:update exits:f2 ohlcv by ticker, date from ohlcv;

The task doesn't seem too difficult and yet kdb+ seems to be making a meal of it. There's gotta be a far more efficient approach. Please help.
Clarification
With regards to the entries, the presumption is that no entry can be taken at the day end (given the granularity of the trading bar). However, any open positions must close at the end of day, or better yet after a given number of bars, unless the take profit condition is met.
Clarification 2
Since entry and exits are booleans in my example. There is an ambiguity when closing open positions at the end of day.
Perhaps it would be better to accord a non-zero index to valid entries and then the exits would be clear, especially at the end of day. However, one can choose whether one wants FIFO or LIFO closing logic. I'll go with FIFO below
I'd rather that this ...
ticker date       close entry exits
-----------------------------------
CSCO   2024.03.15 64    1     0
CSCO   2024.03.15 20    1     0
CSCO   2024.03.15 96    0     1
CSCO   2024.03.15 34    1     1
CSCO   2024.03.15 97    1     1
CSCO   2024.03.15 50    1     0
CSCO   2024.03.15 54    0     1
CSCO   2024.03.15 51    1     0

be
ticker date       close entry exits
-----------------------------------
CSCO   2024.03.15 64    1     0
CSCO   2024.03.15 20    2     0
CSCO   2024.03.15 96    0     1
CSCO   2024.03.15 34    3     2
CSCO   2024.03.15 97    4     3
CSCO   2024.03.15 50    5     0
CSCO   2024.03.15 54    0     4
CSCO   2024.03.15 51    6     5 6


The function needs to be updated to be used with the by clause. The above solution is wrong.

A lot of the logical conditions don't make sense here from a trading perspective, hence the lack of a clear solution. Why is >=1.02 the exit condition - is this a long-only trade simulation? No shorts? If it's long-only, how can a row be both an entry and an exit? Are you closing out all positions at end of day even if they're losing positions? If you're closing out all positions at end of day then is the first row of the next day always an entry?

Thanks for pointing out these issues @terrylynch . Yes, the >= 1.02 is indeed the take profit condition and for the sake of the example I only had long conditions in mind to keep things simple. The example above emerged from an extended discussion below and does not represent trading reality. In practice, no trades are to be entered at the last bar to begin with. However the closing of intraday positions regardless of whether they’re losers is intentional. Please let me know if I’m still missing something.

Got it, thanks for the additional info! The danger with over-simplifying is that the solutions might only work in those simplified scenarios. I don't believe the solutions currently given would work for shorts for example

@terrylynch fair point.

Based on the new clarifications, I think this is what you really want:
q)N:10;
q)/ Note that entry needs to be defined - raw data
q)show t:([] ticker:`CSCO; date:.z.d; close:64 49 82 40 88 77 30 17 23 12; entry:1 2 0 3 4 5 0 6 0 0);
ticker date       close entry
-----------------------------
CSCO   2024.06.23 64    1
CSCO   2024.06.23 49    2
CSCO   2024.06.23 82    0
CSCO   2024.06.23 40    3
CSCO   2024.06.23 88    4
CSCO   2024.06.23 77    5
CSCO   2024.06.23 30    0
CSCO   2024.06.23 17    6
CSCO   2024.06.23 23    0
CSCO   2024.06.23 12    0
q)getExits:{[close;entry]{[x;close;entry]if[entry;x[0],:enlist(close;entry)];$[any exits:2<close-x[0][;0];[x[1]:x[0][;1]where exits;x[0]@:where not exits];x[1]:enlist 0];x}\[(();`long$());close;entry][;1]};
q)/ exits column should be type J
q)/ Any profits>2 will be taken (can close more than one)
q)show t:update exits:getExits[close;entry]by ticker,date from t;
ticker date       close entry exits
-----------------------------------
CSCO   2024.06.23 64    1     ,0
CSCO   2024.06.23 49    2     ,0
CSCO   2024.06.23 82    0     1 2
CSCO   2024.06.23 40    3     ,0
CSCO   2024.06.23 88    4     ,3
CSCO   2024.06.23 77    5     ,0
CSCO   2024.06.23 30    0     ,0
CSCO   2024.06.23 17    6     ,0
CSCO   2024.06.23 23    0     ,6
CSCO   2024.06.23 12    0     ,0
q)/ At end of day, any open positions will be closed
q)show t:update@[exits;count[entry]-1;,;entry[entry]except raze exits]from t;
ticker date       close entry exits
-----------------------------------
CSCO   2024.06.23 64    1     ,0
CSCO   2024.06.23 49    2     ,0
CSCO   2024.06.23 82    0     1 2
CSCO   2024.06.23 40    3     ,0
CSCO   2024.06.23 88    4     ,3
CSCO   2024.06.23 77    5     ,0
CSCO   2024.06.23 30    0     ,0
CSCO   2024.06.23 17    6     ,0
CSCO   2024.06.23 23    0     ,6
CSCO   2024.06.23 12    0     0 4 5

Explanation of getExits function:
getExits:{[close;entry]
    / x[0]:portfolio remaining
    / x[1]:exits
    {[x;close;entry]
        / Checks if entry is non-zero value, add the (close price;entry value) to portfolio
        if[entry;x[0],:enlist(close;entry)];
        / If ANY portfolio matches profit taking, exit
        $[any exits:2<close-x[0][;0];
            [x[1]:x[0][;1]where exits;
            x[0]@:where not exits];
            x[1]:enlist 0];
        x}\[(();`long$());close;entry][;1]
    };


Fantastic! Thanks again @Maurice Lim. I will test your solution and report back.

I tested it, and it works perfectly!

Try this:
q)N:100000;
q)ohlcv:([] ticker:N?`NOK`YHOO`CSCO`ORCL`AAPL`DELL`IBM`MSFT`GOOG; date:asc .z.d-N?100; close:N?100; entry:N?01b);
q)f:{[close;entry]{x[0],:$[z;y;()];if[x[1]:any exits:2<y-x 0;x[0] _:first where exits];x}\[(`long$();0b);close;entry][;1]};
q)\t ohlcv:update exits:f[close;entry]by ticker,date from ohlcv
454
q)10#ohlcv
ticker date       close entry exits
-----------------------------------
MSFT   2024.03.15 95    1     0
GOOG   2024.03.15 71    0     0
DELL   2024.03.15 69    0     0
IBM    2024.03.15 76    0     0
AAPL   2024.03.15 77    1     0
NOK    2024.03.15 68    0     0
AAPL   2024.03.15 6     1     0
YHOO   2024.03.15 8     0     0
ORCL   2024.03.15 40    1     0
ORCL   2024.03.15 16    0     0
q)select from ohlcv where ticker=`MSFT,date=2024.03.15
ticker date       close entry exits
-----------------------------------
MSFT   2024.03.15 95    1     0
MSFT   2024.03.15 20    1     0
MSFT   2024.03.15 14    0     0
MSFT   2024.03.15 46    0     1 / Exit from 20
MSFT   2024.03.15 20    0     0
MSFT   2024.03.15 38    0     0
MSFT   2024.03.15 8     0     0
MSFT   2024.03.15 52    0     0
MSFT   2024.03.15 57    0     0
MSFT   2024.03.15 99    1     1 / Exit from 95
MSFT   2024.03.15 45    0     0
MSFT   2024.03.15 24    1     0
MSFT   2024.03.15 20    1     0
MSFT   2024.03.15 73    0     1 / Exit from 24
MSFT   2024.03.15 37    0     1 / Exit from 20
MSFT   2024.03.15 23    1     0
MSFT   2024.03.15 93    1     1 / Exit from 23
MSFT   2024.03.15 36    0     0
MSFT   2024.03.15 10    0     0
MSFT   2024.03.15 53    1     0
MSFT   2024.03.15 78    1     1 / Exit from 53
..
q)select sum entry,sum exits from ohlcv where ticker=`MSFT,date=2024.03.15 / Sanity check
entry exits
-----------
98    72

I tested that it takes less than a min for 15M rows of intraday data. It is also largely dependent on how many unique ticker/syms there are.
Note that this solution uses FIFO logic for matches but it can be updated to use a different logic like "most profits".
f:{[close;entry]
    {x[0],:$[z;y;()];
        / Solution uses FIFO logic for matches
        if[x[1]:any exits:2<y-x 0;x[0] _:first where exits];
        x}\[(`long$();0b);close;entry][;1]
    };

Example if entry prices are: 24 20.
If the next close is 30. 24 would exit first (due to FIFO logic) rather than 20 which is more profitable.

I am not too sure about how you want to process the data for open positions at end of day.
Does the following solution works? It assumes any open positions will backfill for any close price with no exits.
q)t
ticker date       close entry exits
-----------------------------------
CSCO   2024.03.15 64    1     0
CSCO   2024.03.15 20    1     0
CSCO   2024.03.15 96    0     1
CSCO   2024.03.15 34    1     1
CSCO   2024.03.15 97    1     1
CSCO   2024.03.15 50    1     0
CSCO   2024.03.15 54    0     1
CSCO   2024.03.15 51    1     0
q)exec sum[entry]-sum exits from t / 2 more open positions to close
2i
q)update exits:@[t`exits;(exec sum[entry]-sum exits from t)#reverse where not t`exits;:;1b]from t
ticker date       close entry exits
-----------------------------------
CSCO   2024.03.15 64    1     0
CSCO   2024.03.15 20    1     0
CSCO   2024.03.15 96    0     1
CSCO   2024.03.15 34    1     1
CSCO   2024.03.15 97    1     1
CSCO   2024.03.15 50    1     1 / close by backfilling 2
CSCO   2024.03.15 54    0     1
CSCO   2024.03.15 51    1     1 / close by backfilling 1


Awesome Maurice! On my M1 Mac it takes a manageable 35s to process the entire data set. One more thing, how can I exit at day end if the take profit condition is not met?

Oh yeah, I checked and your solution works perfectly!

For the exit at day end, can entry and exits be together? Example if you have 2 entry by EOD with no exits. Then you want to exit at those entry points? Would be good if you update the question with some example outputs.

That's great to know that the solution works!

My presumption was that no entry can be taken at the day end (given the granularity of the trading bar). However, any open positions must close at day end.  I have clarified it above.

I have added a section for closing at EOD for open positions by backfilling but unsure if that is what you expect. If you could add in an expected input and output that might help.

Yes, that's an important point. I have mentioned it in clarification 2 above. Let me know if you'd like anything further.

@marital_weeping I have added a new answer based on your new clarifications.
